# What is the TypeScript equivalent of “PropTypes.oneOfType”?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import myOwnShape from './myOwnShape';

export default PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.oneOfType([
        myOwnShape,
        PropTypes.shape({
            a: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
            b: PropTypes.arrayOf(myOwnShape).isRequired
        }),
    ]),
);
```

written in TS:

```
import myOwnShape from './myOwnShape';

export interface subFoo {
    a: any,
    b: myOwnShape[]
}

// what about the rest of code...
```

how to write array interface and `PropTypes.oneOfType` in TS.
I don't want to use `prop-types`, is there anything possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: [Ref](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide/blob/212d23e6daa418afc16d7b6b93631266544e357f/TicTacToe_TS/src/constants.ts#L1-L2)

```
export type Array<Foo> = [myOwnShape | subFoo];
```

Comment: 1. Don't use name `Array` (this will hide the real Array type) 2. You're defining generic type parameter `Foo` but not using it. 3. The defined type is tuple with a single element, is this what you're looking for? (It is not the same as `PropTypes.arrayOf`). I suggest you to go over basic types first of all https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @AlekseyL. any better idea equals to ```PropTypes.arrayOf```, thanks

Comment: `type SomeProp = Array<Foo | Bar>` - array with elements of type `Foo` or `Bar`